# Trilateration C# How to get back into "normal" coordinates?

Tags: c#, math, geometry

I am trying to calculate my location with help of 3 stations (p1,p2,p3) with radius (r1,r2,r3). Stations are in 3D space.

- Example 1:

P1=(2,2,0), P2=(3,3,0), P3=(1,4,0)
r1=1 r2=1 r3=1.4142

Result should be: P=(2,3,0)

- Example 2:

P1=(2,1,0), P2=(4,3,0), P3=(4,4,1)
r1=2, r2=2, r3=2.449

Result should be: P=(2,3,0)

My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3;

    double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out x1);
    double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out x2);
    double.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out x3);
    double.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out y1);
    double.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out y2);
    double.TryParse(textBox6.Text, out y3);
    double.TryParse(textBox7.Text, out z1);
    double.TryParse(textBox8.Text, out z2);
    double.TryParse(textBox9.Text, out z3);


    Vector3D p1 = new Vector3D(x1, y1, z1);
    Vector3D p2 = new Vector3D(x2, y2, z2);
    Vector3D p3 = new Vector3D(x3, y3, z3);

    Vector3D p_1 = new Vector3D();
    Vector3D p_2 = new Vector3D();
    Vector3D p_3 = new Vector3D();

    Vector3D xn = new Vector3D();
    Vector3D yn = new Vector3D();
    Vector3D zn = new Vector3D();
    double r1_pow, r2_pow, r3_pow;

    double.TryParse(textBox10.Text, out r1_pow);
    double.TryParse(textBox11.Text, out r2_pow);
    double.TryParse(textBox12.Text, out r3_pow);


    //r1_pow = p1.Length;
    // r2_pow = p2.Length;
    //r3_pow = p3.Length;
    double X, Y, Z1, Z2, d, i, j;
    p_1 = p2 - p1;
    p_2 = p3 - p1;
    xn = Vector3D.Divide(p_1, p_1.Length);
    i = Vector3D.DotProduct(xn, p_2);
    d = p_1.Length;
    yn = Vector3D.Divide((p_2 - (i * xn)), (p_2 - (i * xn)).Length);
    j = Vector3D.DotProduct(yn, p_2);
    zn = Vector3D.CrossProduct(xn, yn);
    X = ((r1_pow * r1_pow) - (r2_pow * r2_pow) + (d * d)) / (2 * d);
    Y = (((r1_pow * r1_pow) - (r3_pow * r3_pow) + (i * i) + (j * j)) / (2 * j)) - ((i / j) * X);
    double X2 = X * X;
    double Y2 = Y * Y;
    Z1 = Math.Sqrt((r1_pow * r1_pow) - Math.Round(X2, 1) - Math.Round(Y2, 1));
    Z2 = -Math.Sqrt((r1_pow * r1_pow) - Math.Round(X2, 1) - Math.Round(Y2, 1));



    double a, B;
    Vector3D k2 = new Vector3D();
    Vector3D k1 = new Vector3D();
    k1 = p1 + ((X * xn) + (Y * yn) + (Z1 * zn));
    //  k1.Normalize();
    k2 = p1 + (X * xn) + (Y * yn) - (Z2 * zn);

    MessageBox.Show(k1.ToString());
}
```

So my question is what does K1 and K2 means. I am guessing it has to do something with going back to "normal" coordinates but I do not understand the real concept of this two equations. And how am I suppost to get P (the result) from that K1 and K2?

K1 = P1 + X * Xn + Y*Yn + z1*Zn

K2 = P1 + X * Xn + Y*Yn - z2*Zn

Comment: Why do you need the intersection?  All you would need is when they make contact, or maybe the center.  Can the stations float into each other or do they have actual mass and break apart when they collide?

Comment: An important part here: is this a real world or just an abstract math question? In the real world the 3 circles usually do not intersect in a single point and give you some area (so you need some additional logic to pick a single point from there). In the abstract math world the answer might be guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: This is more of a abstract math question.

Comment: your code converts your problem to 2D by projecting onto plane the stations forms where `Xn,Yn,Zn` are the basis vectors.  the K1,K2 are the equations you want to use and chose the solution that makes sense... so if you know the ground height compute altitude of resulting K1,K2 and throw away point which is either underground or in sky (unless your object is a plane or underground drill).

Comment: Yes I am throwing away the K3 point. I've managed to solve the first example but just can't get the second one to work.

Comment: Cross post of: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/406036/392